# React app not loading js file when accessing it with a non home page url

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have a **react app** which I serve with **nodejs backend**. My requirement is to inject a variable from node server to react code when it is running. When I access the app with the home page URL it works fine but not with other URLs. I am going to put more details to understand the complete scenario.

In node server I have code to create a file like this: **dist** folder is where react build is stored

```
    fs.writeFileSync(
      path.join(__dirname, "../dist", "config.js"),
      `window.INJECTED_VARIABLE= { value: "qwerty", }`
    );
```

In public > index.html I have this script to load the created config.js file.

```
<script src="./config.js"></script>
```

Now, when I run my node server and access my app with the home URL **http://localhost:3000**, I am able to access the injected value - window.INJECTED_VARIABLE as { value: "qwerty", } and config file is also present under "**sources**" tab in chrome devtools.

I have one page in my app - **http://localhost:3000/profile/profileId**, when I directly open my app with this URL, I see window.INJECTED_VARIABLE as undefined. It looks like there is no config file in **source** tab if we look in chrome devtools.

**I am getting a same problem in production too.**

Can anyone explain this behavior and help me in fixing it. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: `./config.js` is relative to the current path, _i.e._ a document served from `/profile/profileId` is going to request the file `/profile/profileId/config.js` if you mean to specify from the root, omit the dot: `src="/config.js"`

Comment: @Emissary Thank you so much!!!!, I updated it to "/config.js" and it is working!!. I killed so much time thinking about it. Thanks for the explanation. Appreciate it. You can post it as an answer if you would like.

Comment: No worries, typos are the worst!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot in `./config.js` denotes a URL relative to the current path. *i.e.* A document served from `/profile/profileId` will request the file `/profile/profileId/config.js` - which doesn't exist.

To specify that a partial URL always be from the root, you should omit the dot.

```html
<script src="/config.js"></script>
```